# Batch Error SQL Server BULK INSERT

Tags: batch, batch-file, sql-server, sql

I am attempting to have a script in my batch file that runs a SQL Server Stored Procedure. The Stored Procedure bulk inserts data from a .CSV file into a SQL Server table. When I run the Stored Procedure on SQL Server, it runs with no issues. However when I try to get it to work in my batch file, it fails

My batch script is

```
set STEP_NBR=STEP113
set SQL_Script_Name= CST_SN_ADD_SPS_CUSTOMER_ORDER_STG_TMP
set ERROR_MSG=%STEP_NBR% %SQL_Script_Name%
call "%DIR_BAT%\CreateLAFMessage.bat" "%~n0.bat-> %STEP_NBR% - Running %SQL_Script_Name%.sql" %_LAF_MSG_DETAILS%
SQLCMD.EXE %SQLCMD_VARS% -S%DB_SERVER_NAME% -d%DB_SP01_NAME% -w2048 -E -b -i"%DIR_SQL%\%SQL_Script_Name%.sql" -o"%DIR_LOG%\%SQL_Script_Name%.lst"
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 GOTO ON_ERROR
```

The SQL Script calls out the Stored Procedure

```
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CST_SN_ADD_SPS_CUSTOMER_ORDER_STG_TMP]
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

And the Stored Procedure

```
USE [LVSDB_DRP01]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo]. 
[CST_SN_ADD_SPS_CUSTOMER_ORDER_STG_TMP]    Script Date: 9/10/2018 10:28:30 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[CST_SN_ADD_SPS_CUSTOMER_ORDER_STG_TMP] 
as 
BEGIN

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

IF OBJECT_ID('staging.dbo.ADD_CUSTOMER_ORDER_STG_TMP', 'U') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE [staging].[dbo].[ADD_CUSTOMER_ORDER_STG_TMP](
[ITEM_INDX] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[LOC_INDX] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CUST_ORD_INDX] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CUST_ORD_LIN_NBR] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CUST_ORD_ORD_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
[CUST_ORD_QTY] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CUST_SHP_QTY] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[SET_ITEM_INDX] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[HEADER_COMPONENT] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[BUCKET] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)

IF OBJECT_ID('staging.dbo.ADD_CUSTOMER_ORDER_STG_TMP', 'U') IS NOT NULL
Truncate table staging.dbo.ADD_CUSTOMER_ORDER_STG_TMP;

IF OBJECT_ID('staging.dbo.ADD_CUSTOMER_ORDER_STG_TMP', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BULK INSERT staging.dbo.ADD_CUSTOMER_ORDER_STG_TMP
FROM '\\usashsmdbpcw02f\C$\SNI_Logility\ADD_CUSTOMER_ORDER_STG.csv'
WITH 
  (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    FIRSTROW = 2
--    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
  );

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

The Stored Procedure runs on SQL Server, so I assume my error is in the batch script, or potentially permissions for the file pathway

Comment: Try adding a login you have defined on this SQL access which you know and can confirm has at least read access to the `\\usashsmdbpcw02f\C$\SNI_Logility\ADD_CUSTOMER_ORDER_STG.csv` by adding `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'domain\username';` to the SP somewhere before the `BULK INSERT` statement and see if that makes any difference. Executing the SP from SSMS versus sqlcmd there could very well be security differences that SP execute as per each way so specifying for the SP to change to a security context explicitly within the script that you knows has access to a file share should resolve at this level.

Comment: It'd probably be helpful to also disclose what error message you are getting or see when it does not work as expected. Try running each command on the command line rather than in the batch script and find at which point you see the first error when you break it up and run it manually via command line and [edit] your question to tell about this detail. I can think of a few things based on your current wording and my first comment was just one so maybe add more detail and tell what error you get and at what point in the process when you run the correlated commands manually via command line.

Comment: And don't forget that `\\usashsmdbpcw02f\C$` is a hidden admin share so I assume this means running the SP on the SQL Server where it works is because when you do it from there, that security context has access to that hidden admin share on the `usashsmdbpcw02f` named machine.